# How to export triggers from a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to generate a script/extract all of the triggers I have in database, so that I can use them in another one. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to (wanna is not an English word) generate a script that contains the definition of all your triggers?

Comment: sorry for my bad English. I have written triggers for a few tables. I want these triggers to execute them in the other database.

Comment: No problem. I just find `wanna` very annoying :) If my edit is not ok (i.e. i did not understand you properly), you can roll it back.

Comment: No, I don't use sqlserver. But [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507755/how-do-i-list-or-export-the-code-for-all-triggers-in-a-database) could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of triggers from `sys.all_objects` (`sysobjects` on 2000) and then the code from `sp_helptext` procedure.

Example:
http://databases.aspfaq.com/schema-tutorials/schema-how-do-i-show-all-the-triggers-in-a-database.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find trigger objects either on [`sys.objects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) view with an [`xtype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16243857/1366033) = `'tr'` or, starting in SQL 2008, on the [`sys.triggers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188746.aspx) view.

You can get the definition for triggers (or any other object) by joining to  [`sys.sql_modules.definition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) or by calling [`OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx).
<sub>Just don't use [`sys.syscomments.text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx) because it caps out at `nvarchar(4000)`</sub>

In any combination of the above (really doesn't matter) you could generate a single file to populate all of your scripts by terminating each definition with "Go" like this:

```sql
SELECT m.definition, 'GO'
FROM sys.triggers tr
JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON tr.object_id = m.object_id
```

Just take the resulting output and save it in a single file and execute to recreate every trigger.

#### Generate Individual Scripts

The problem is a little more complex if you want to generate individual files for each script.
<sup>...mostly in automating the file generation; the previous solution leans on just presenting data and letting you save it.</sup>

You can use [`bcp utility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), but I find SQL to be pretty clumsy at dealing with generating files.  Alternatively, just grab the data in powershell and then generate files from there where you have a lot more fine tuned access and control.  Here's a script that will grab all the triggers and create them into folders for each table.

```bash
# config
$server = "serverName"
$database = "dbName"
$dirPath = 'C:\triggers'

# query
$query = @"
SELECT TOP 5
       t.name AS TableName, 
       tr.name AS TriggerName,
       m.definition As TriggerScript
FROM sys.triggers tr
    JOIN sys.tables t ON tr.parent_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON tr.object_id = m.object_id
"@

# connection
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True"
$sqlConnection.Open()

# command
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $sqlConnection)
$sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 10 * 60 # 10 minutes


# execute
$reader = $sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read())
{
    # get reader values
    $tableName = $reader.GetValue(0)
    $triggerName = $reader.GetValue(1)
    $triggerScript = $reader.GetValue(2)

    $filepath = "$dirPath\$tableName\$triggerName.sql"

    # ensure  directory exists
    [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$dirPath\$tableName\")

    # write file
    New-Item -Path $filepath -Value $triggerScript -ItemType File
}
$reader.Close()
$sqlConnection.Close()
```