# Is there a table that holds the listing of sysobjects.xtype descriptions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

According to [the sysobjects documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx), `sysobjects.xtype` can be one of these object types:

```
| xtype |              Description              |
|-------|---------------------------------------|
| AF    |  Aggregate function (CLR)             |
| C     |  CHECK constraint                     |
| D     |  Default or DEFAULT constraint        |
| F     |  FOREIGN KEY constraint               |
| L     |  Log                                  |
| FN    |  Scalar function                      |
| FS    |  Assembly (CLR) scalar-function       |
| FT    |  Assembly (CLR) table-valued function |
| IF    |  In-lined table-function              |
| IT    |  Internal table                       |
| P     |  Stored procedure                     |
| PC    |  Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure      |
| PK    |  PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K)   |
| RF    |  Replication filter stored procedure  |
| S     |  System table                         |
| SN    |  Synonym                              |
| SQ    |  Service queue                        |
| TA    |  Assembly (CLR) DML trigger           |
| TF    |  Table function                       |
| TR    |  SQL DML Trigger                      |
| TT    |  Table type                           |
| U     |  User table                           |
| UQ    |  UNIQUE constraint (type is K)        |
| V     |  View                                 |
| X     |  Extended stored procedure            |
```

and I could put those into a `CASE` statement, but is there a table I can just join on to lookup that `xtype` description? I know `systypes` isn't that table. I mean, I've just kind of memorized a lot of them, but I'm doing some research on a database and it's foreign to me (i.e. I don't know a ton about it) and so I'd like to build that description into this query without a `CASE` statement:

```sql
select object_name(c.id), c.name, [length], o.xtype from syscolumns c
    join sysobjects o on o.id = c.id
where c.name like '%job%code%'
```

Update

Below is the end result after the answer by SQLMenace. I felt it necessary to place here because it's not just a straight forward `join`.

```sql
select object_name(c.id), c.name, t.name, c.[length], o.xtype, x.name from syscolumns c
    join sysobjects o on o.id = c.id
    join systypes t on t.xtype = c.xtype
    join master..spt_values x on x.name like '%' + o.xtype + '%' and x.type = 'O9T'
where c.name like '%job%code%'
order by c.xtype
```

Comment: I think the JOIN returns duplicates if the object is a trigger as it finds (for me) 2 matchs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is this

```
SELECT name 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'O9T'
```

Output

```
AF: aggregate function
AP: application
C : check cns
D : default (maybe cns)
EN: event notification
F : foreign key cns
FN: scalar function
FS: assembly scalar function
FT: assembly table function
IF: inline function
IS: inline scalar function
IT: internal table
L : log
P : stored procedure
PC : assembly stored procedure
PK: primary key cns
R : rule
RF: replication filter proc
S : system table
SN: synonym
SQ: queue
TA: assembly trigger
TF: table function
TR: trigger
U : user table
UQ: unique key cns
V : view
X : extended stored proc
sysobjects.type, reports
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!! I edited my question with the end result because the `join` is a little different than the norm, so everybody could get a clear picture of how I joined to it.

Comment: For some reason ``TT: table type`` is missing from the query result.  Also ``PC : assembly stored procedure`` has an extra space before the colon, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with to get total of database objects and its description.

```
    select xtype1, Description, total_count, last_crdate, last_refdate 
    from 
    (SELECT xtype as xtype1, total_count = COUNT(*), last_crdate = MAX(crdate), last_refdate = MAX(refdate)
     FROM sysobjects 
     GROUP BY xtype
     )o
    left outer join 
    (SELECT LEFT(name,PATINDEX('%:%',name)-1) AS xtype2, RIGHT(name, (LEN(name) - PATINDEX('%:%',name))) AS Description
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE type = 'O9T' AND number  = -1
    )x 
    on o.xtype1 = x.xtype2
    order by Description;
```